# Vimeo in lightbox - fullscreen not working in chrome

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, fullscreen, vimeo

I am experiencing an issue in chrome. I am using a wordpress plugin to popup a vimeo embed. Everything looks perfect, except for when you click the full screen icon in the vimeo controls.

The page jumps to full screen but you can only see about a quarter of the video in the top left corner of the browser, on top of the page content that should be hidden by the full screen video.

Please advise!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. There was an unsupported issue with the plugin I was using. #wpproblems